# can't save image in postgresql. column "data" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint

Tags: postgresql, java-17, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

I have spring-boot-starter-parent v3.1.2 with hibernate v6.2.6.
I am trying to save byte[] to postgresql and get the next error

```
column "data" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I have found some solution for hibernate v5 like this
`@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ImageType")` and `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")` but nothing for v6

Any ideas?

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "image")
@ToString(exclude = {"data"})
public class ImageEntity {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "content_type")
    private String contentType;

    @Lob
    private byte [] data;
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.image")
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        ImageEntity imageEntity = new ImageEntity();
        imageEntity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        imageEntity.setFileName("image.jpg");
        imageEntity.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        imageEntity.setData(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("image.jpg")));

        imageRepository.save(imageEntity);
    }
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.image (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    file_name varchar(255) NULL,
    content_type varchar(255) NULL,
    "data" bytea NULL,
    CONSTRAINT image_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

in case you not found the answer already on stackoverflow.
This explains it well: [Unable to use Spring Data JPA to extract users that have a byte[] of a profile Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985717/unable-to-use-spring-data-jpa-to-extract-users-that-have-a-byte-of-a-profile-i)

In short: you use postgres type bytea, Hibernate (6.2) uses `@Lob` annotation to try and use postgres OID mechanism. If you remove `@Lob` it uses the correct mapping.
I think you also have to add:

```
@Column(name = "data", columnDefinition="bytea")
```

to your data field.

Kind regards,
Knut

Comment: Worked for me using PostgreSQL 13